# loading pdf files into webview in b4a android

Tags: pdf, load

i have tried to load PDF file into webView in b4a android but, in running app in simulator show nothing without error .
does anyone know how i can load a PDF file into webView in b4a android?

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In b4x forum, I have read that, android webview does not support pdf files.